# Why would rasagullas break while cooking?

Tags: indian-cuisine, paneer

My latest batch of rasagullas were a disaster. As soon as I dropped them into the cooker, they started disintegrating. I realized the entire affair will turn out to be a super waste of effort and time.

I did cut some corners last time:
1. Did I not dry the curd enough?
2. Did I not knead the curd enough?
3. Was the sugar syrup used for boiling not saturated enough?

Any clues?

Comment: Can we get the recipe you used?  What corners did you cut?

Comment: it might be due to you may be using paneer made from buffalo's milk,for making softer rasagullas you should use paneer of cow's milk.

Comment: @rfusca, the not-drying-the-curd-enough and not-kneading-the-dough-enough corners might have been cut...

Comment: @Sunishtha_Singh, I am not sure if I am using cow's milk, but have used the same milk earlier, and have dished out excellent (from my perspective) rosogollas...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the water content of the rasgullas cause it to break.

To make sure that they're ready, after you drain the water from the paneer, take a bit of paneer on your palm and knead it with your thumb for about 40 seconds. You should be able to roll out a firm yet [smooth ball](http://belesaaru.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/imgp51281.jpg) off it. If you can't form balls, it means you will have to squeeze out more water from the paneer. In the end you should have something like a soft dough.

It takes a while to get it just right. If you can't make perfect balls in your first few shots at it, you can make rasmalai/ kheer/paneer pedas out of it, so it won't be a wasteful disaster after-all.

<sub>Refer to these articles/videos:</sub> 
<sub>Sources : 
[1](http://saffronapron.blogspot.com/2009/01/blog-warming-spongy-rasgulla.html), [2](http://belesaaru.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/rasgulla/), [3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kitRy8U1PGs), [4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqLzqg662vs&list=PLDE0C27C078984BBE&index=41&feature=plpp_video)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The paneer was probably too watery. You can try drying it with a fan for 4 minutes.

Comment: Hello! This space is reserved for new answers. I wasn't sure if you are suggesting drying with a fan as a new answer, or complaining that you are still unable to form balls and requesting more answers. If the second, then I'm afraid that writing a new post won't really help, so I would have had to delete it. So I chose the first interpretation and edited it, making the fan-drying you suggest an answer.